# on_guild_join discord python why does this not work?

Tags: python, discord

This is my code that initiates ofc when it joins a server.

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        name = str(guild.name)
        description = str(guild.description)
        member_count = str(guild.member_count)
        channel_count = str(len(guild.channels))
        id = str(guild.id)
        region = str(guild.region)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=tit + " Was invited to " + name)
        if guild.description == True:
            embed.add_field(title="Description", value=description)
        embed.add_field(title="ID", value=id)
        embed.add_field(title="Member Count", value=f"Count: {member_count}")
        embed.add_field(title="Channel Count", value=channel_count)
        embed.add_field(title="Region", value=region)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        await guild_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the error

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/DiscordBots/DefaultRobloxTools/cogs/CommandEvents.py", line 58, in on_guild_join
    embed = discord.Embed(title=tit + " Was invited to " + name)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'str'
```

What's wrong I do not quite understand this error message.

Comment: What exactly is `tit`, you don't seem to have included it in your code, as the error tells you  `tit` is a function and not a string. If you show the definition of tit, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @Ceres tit is a string, tit consists of "Bloxy Tools"

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the string in wrong format it should be

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=(tit + " Was invited to " + name))
```

instead of

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=tit + " Was invited to " + name)
```

Comment: This doesn't help, still getting same error